# Given a series of characters from stdin, print their squared integer ASCII counterparts

Tags: c, comparative-review, io

This program in essence is extremely simple, however, it can be written in many different ways. I'm a beginner at C and I've written it in 5 different variations (mostly differing in the use of `getchar` over `scanf`, `while` over `do while` loops..).

Apart from readability and/or maintainability, is there any difference between these 5 code blocks (such as perhaps performance or efficiency, if we disregard the use of `getchar` over `scanf`)?

```
unsigned char d;
```

1. ```
   while (1)
       while(scanf("%c", &d), d != '\n') {
           printf("%d\n", d * d);
       }
   ```
2. ```
   do {
       scanf(" %c", &d);
       printf("%d\n", d * d);
   } while (1);
   ```
3. ```
   while (1)
       while((d = getchar()) != '\n') { //could also be written as while(d = getchar(), d != '\n')
           printf("%d\n", d * d);
       }
   ```
4. ```
   while ((d = getchar())) {
       if(d == '\n')
           continue;
       printf("%d\n", d * d);
   }
   ```
5. ```
   do {
       d = getchar();
       if(d == '\n')
           continue;
       printf("%d\n", d * d);
   } while (1);
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> while (1)
>     while(scanf("%c", &d), d != '\n') {
>         printf("%d\n", d * d);
>     }
> ```

It's better to consistently add braces around the body of statements like `while` and `if`.
A common mistake is to write something like this:

```
while (1)
    while(scanf("%c", &d), d != '\n') {
        printf("%d\n", d * d);
    }
    printf("...");
```

This may mislead a reader to think that the last `printf` is part of the outer loop, when it isn't. Just put the braces around the body always.

Another negative point in this version is having two statements inside the inner `while`. This is not easy to read. It's better to write in a way that there is no more than one statement per line. More generally, I recommend to avoid the `,` operator entirely.

The same point applies to this line in the 3rd version:

> ```
> while((d = getchar()) != '\n') {
> ```

That is, there is an assignment within the conditional statement.
Avoid such "clever" writing style.
Stick to one statement per line.

And one more variation of the same issue, in the 4th version:

> ```
> while ((d = getchar())) {
> ```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "most but not all skip `\n`" though? I've tested all of the examples, none of them catch `\n` and `100` is never printed.

Comment: @BogdanM. Indeed you're right. I thought v2 does not skip `\n` like the others do, but in fact it does. It seems to be thanks to the space in the format string of `scanf(" %c", &d);`. This is confusing code that's best to avoid.

Comment: I don't think *any* of them terminate when standard input is closed.

Comment: @TobySpeight I mistakenly thought v4 does. But you're right, it doesn't thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug common to all 5 versions: we should *always* test whether the read was successful.

- For `scanf()`: did it return `1`, when we asked for one conversion?
- For `getchar()`: did it return `EOF`?

  Note, in particular, that narrowing the result of `getchar()` (which is `int`) to an `unsigned char` loses the ability to distinguish `EOF` from a valid character.

Here's a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int d;
    while ((d = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (d != '\n')
            printf("%d\n", d * d);
    }
}
```

Finally, a pedantic note: this will only work on ASCII values *when run on an ASCII system/locale*.  In other words, C always uses the environment's character coding, and does not convert input to a fixed representation as done by, say, Java.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to performance, the only real way to know which method that is faster is to benchmark it. In many cases we can make educated guesses, but nothing can replace testing the code. Once snippet may win over another for various of reasons.

Apart from that, the biggest flaw is that you don't check for errors. `getchar` returns `EOF` on error. (Or of course end of file) `scanf` returns the number of successful assignments on success, and otherwise a negative value is returned.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes it does. `scanf("%c", &x)` will *read* a character from stdin and *write* it to the variable `x`. The return value from scanf is the number of *written* characters, not the number of *read* characters.

Comment: @TobySpeight But yes, it is a bit ambiguous (and my post was slightly wrong) so I changed it. Thanks.